# Is the CDF derived from the estimated survival function a valid statistic

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

Let $S(t)= 1 - F(t)$ be the survival function for the random variable $T$ with CDF $F(t)$. This can be estimated both nonparametrically (via Kaplan-Meier) or parametrically (via Breslow). If we estimate the survival function with either method and then calculate $1 - S(t)$, is this a valid way to estimate the CDF?

Motivated in part by: "[From Survival function to Cumulative density function (CDF), does CDF properties hold?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531927/from-survival-function-to-cumulative-density-function-cdf-does-cdf-properties)"

Comment: How do you define "valid" in this setting?

Comment: Valid in this setting means that $1 - S(t)$ is statistically meaningful, in that it has similar interpretation as the CDF. If I was interested in the probability that death occurred before $t$, then the quantity $1 - S(t)$ works (estimated both non / semi parametrically).

Comment: If the constraint is that vague then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no censoring of event times and no covariate modeling, then there is no problem. In that situation, you simply have an empirical survival function and a corresponding empirical CDF.

If the last observed time is censored rather than an event, then $S(t)$ never becomes zero so you never get to the point where $F(t)=1$. That doesn't mean that your estimate up to that time is invalid, just that you can't estimate either $S(t)$ or $F(t)$ beyond that time with a non-parametric or semi-parametric model.*

If there is censoring but the last observation is of an event, there's an interesting distinction among ways of estimating $S(t)$.

The Nelson-Aalen estimator (extended by Breslow to the situation with covariates in a semi-parametric model) is based on the cumulative hazard $\Lambda(t)$. You estimate $S(t)=\exp (-\Lambda(t))$. As the empirical cumulative hazard in a finite sample never becomes infinite, $S(t)$ from a Breslow-Nelson-Aalen estimate never becomes 0. Again, you never get to the high-$t$ tail of the survival function or CDF with that estimate. Does that make the estimate "invalid"? That depends on your definition.

With a Kaplan-Meier estimate from data having the last observation time an event, $S(t)$ is 0 at and beyond the last observation; similarly, $F(t) =1$ thereafter. Kalbfleisch and Prentice extended the Kaplan-Meier product-limit estimate to the semi-parametric case, so their method also provides an estimate out to $F(t)=1$ in that case. [This paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.4172%2F2155-6180.1000392), for example, compares the Kalbfleisch-Prentice and Breslow estimators. AdamO provides links to references on ways to estimate baseline hazard [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/445987/28500).

Keep the distinction between the cumulative-hazard (Nelson-Aalen, Breslow) and product-limit (Kaplan-Meier, Kalbfleisch-Prentice) approaches in mind. Both are "valid" approaches but they can lead to differences in detail.

---

*The Breslow estimate is typically used in a semi-parametric model (e.g., Cox model) rather than in a fully parametric model as this question might be taken to imply. With a fully parametric model you have specified both the form of the baseline survival and any dependence on covariates as part of the model.